# Permissions of newly created files on NAS mount

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions, network-attached-storage

I've mounted a NAS partition as follows:

```
server:/volume1/public            /mnt/public             nfs  rw,suid,nodev,noexec,auto,user,async 0 0
```

All available files are both readable and writable under a non-sudo user. However, once I create a new file as a non-sudo user it gets **4 permissions and the only time I can edit it as a non-sudo user is during it's creation. Example:

```
touch /mnt/public/hi
ll /mnt/public/
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobody nobody     0  1. Mai 13:10 hi
#current user is not in nobody group
```

And that is wrong, since other previously created files (I assume on win machines) have 777 permissions. I need at least **6 to be there. Any advice?

/etc/exports on the server side:

```
/volume1/public server-ip/24(rw,async,no_wdelay,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

I have a user on client side with:

```
user:x:1000:1000:user:/home/user:/bin/bash
```

Comment: this is because, the nas map every use to nobody, look the parameters anonuid and anongid.

Comment: @c4f4t0r I've assigned to those parameters values of uid/gid that I need on my client system, restarted the service, remouted clients and it still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: you need that paramater in the server side.

Comment: @c4f4t0r yep, that's what I did, changed the /etc/exports on the server using uid/gid of the user on client system, restarted nfs on server, remounted partition on client side, still the same problem. See the question for /etc/exports file contents

Comment: you have the the uid 1000 in the server side too?

Comment: @c4f4t0r no, there's nothing with uid 1000 or gid 1000 on the server side.